# How can I pass a service into an AngularJS directive when the function is not inside the directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive:

```
app.directive('htmlTemplate', htmlTemplate);

function htmlTemplate() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return "/Content/app/admin/templates/" + attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}
```

I have seen numerous examples of directives where everything is contained into one block but not where the function is seperate like here.

Can someone tell me how I can inject stateService into the directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without minification protection:

```
app.directive('htmlTemplate', htmlTemplate);

function htmlTemplate(stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return "/Content/app/admin/templates/" + attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}
```

With minification protection:

```
app.directive('htmlTemplate', ['stateService', htmlTemplate]);

function htmlTemplate(stateService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return "/Content/app/admin/templates/" + attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice and clear, unlike some other answers I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Since parameters are injected dynamically, you may try this :

```
app.service("YourService", function() {

});

app.directive('htmlTemplate',['YourService', htmlTemplate]);

function htmlTemplate(yourService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return "/Content/app/admin/templates/" + attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.stateService = stateService;
        }
    };
}
```